# How to add a user-friendly option to link to nodes from body text or text-field?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I'm looking for an option or module that provides the possibility to link to other internal nodes avoiding the usage of full html in a text field. Users should be able to highlight a term and assign a link to it. It would be nice to have a kind of select-list containing the available nodes to link to.

I have done this before, but only for external links and with a minified editor. But i have no idea how to put a list of nodes there. Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [LinkIt](http://drupal.org/project/linkit) module.

> Linkit provides an easy interface for internal and external linking.
>   Linkit links to nodes, users, managed files, terms and have basic
>   support for all entities by default, using an autocomplete field. In
>   7.x-2.4 there is also support for fields (text, textarea, and link).

If you have pretty paths I'd also suggest combining it with [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic), that way your links will have their path aliases applied rather than their direct links (i.e. *node/123* will become *about-us*)

Comment: Thanks, Chapabu. That's exactly what I'm looking for. How could i miss that thang? :) I really did an extended search before...

Comment: It's easy to do sometimes :)